# How to make emoji images come out of left when it moves out of the div box? vice versa and for top and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im new to Javascript so apologies if its not good.
Im trying create an emoji app where user selects 3 emojis.
Right now you can drag the emojis around the screen which makes it abit interactive.
however when you drag outside the div box they disappear.
How would i make it so that when the user drags outside of the div box, it comes out the other side. e.g. drag image left and comes out right , drag image above, comes out bottom

Any suggestions? not expecting an answer but ideas would be helpful.

HTML

```
  </head>
<body onload="move('dragemoji');">
    <div class="bg">
        <div class= "container-progress">
            <div class="progress-container">
                <div class ="progress" id="progress"></div>
                <div class ="circle active">0%</div>
                <div class ="circle active">25%</div>
                <div class="circle active">50%</div>
                <div class="circle">75%</div>
                <div class="circle">100%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container",id="container">
            <a href="/HTML/nayamiShikou.html"><article class="arrows prev"></article></a>
            <article id= "anshin-bubbleID"class="anshinBubble">.</article> 
            <article class="option">
            </article>
            <div class="canvas">
                <div class = "emoji-container">
                    <div class="emoji" id="smile"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="sad"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="normal"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="shocked"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="cry"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="sick"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="suprised"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="verySad"></div>
                    <div class="emoji" id="worried"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="anshinMsgBtn" id="anshin-msg-btn" onclick="anshinChoice()"><a id="anshinMsgBtnTxt">OK</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/JS/myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.canvas{
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40rem;
    left:33rem;
    width:1500px;
    height:500px;
    border: 10px var(--clr--color3) solid;
    background-color: var(--clr--color1);
    z-index: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#canvas{
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.emoji-container{
    display:flex;
}
.emoji-container .emoji{
    width:125px;
    height:125px;
    margin: 5px;
}
#emoji-choice{
    top:50rem;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 70px;
    background-color: var(--clr--color1);
    border: 5px var(--clr--color3) solid;
}
#smile{
    content: url(/emotions/happyEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#smile.smile-text{
}
#sad{
    content: url(/emotions/sadEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 23rem;
    left: 5rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#cry{
    content: url(/emotions/cryEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20rem;
    left: 30rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#normal{
    content: url(/emotions/normalEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 18rem;
    left: 77rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#shocked{
    content: url(/emotions/shockedEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 6rem;
    left: 56rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#sick{
    content: url(/emotions/sickEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 14rem;
    left: 44rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#suprised{
    content: url(/emotions/suprisedEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    left: 24rem;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#verySad{
    content: url(/emotions/verySad.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 69rem;    
    cursor:pointer;
}
#worried{
    content: url(/emotions/worriedEmoji.png);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 1rem;
    left: 39rem;
    left: 69rem;    cursor:pointer;

}
```

JS

```
var emoji;
var emojiMsg = document.getElementById("checkMessage");
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("canvas")
var smileEmoji =  document.getElementById("smile");
var sadEmoji = document.getElementById("sad");
var cryEmoji = document.getElementById("cry");
var emojiCount = 1;


const move = function(dragEmoji){
    const emojis = document.querySelectorAll(".emoji");
    emojis.forEach(dragEmoji => {
        dragEmoji.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
            dragEmoji.style.position = "absolute";
            emoji = dragEmoji;
            document.onmousemove = (e) =>{
                emojiHitWall(dragEmoji)
                if(emojiCount<4){
                    if(emoji.style.height==200+"px"){
                        var x = e.pageX;
                        var y = e.pageY;
                        emoji.style.left = x -605 + "px";
                        emoji.style.top = y -740+ "px";
                        preventDefault();
                    }else{
                        var x = e.pageX;
                        var y = e.pageY;
                        emoji.style.left = x -605 + "px";
                        emoji.style.top = y -740+ "px";
                        emoji.style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
                        preventDefault();
                    }

                }else{
                    var x = e.pageX;
                    var y = e.pageY;
                    emoji.style.left = x -605 + "px";
                    emoji.style.top = y -740+ "px";
                    preventDefault();
                }
            }
            document.onmouseup = function(e){
                if(emojiCount<4){
                    if(emoji.style.height == 200+"px"){
                        emoji.style.width = 150+"px";
                        emoji.style.height = 150+"px";
                        emoji.style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
                        emoji = null;
                        emojiCount--;
                    }else{
                        emoji.style.width = 200+"px";
                        emoji.style.height = 200+"px";
                        emoji.style.filter="grayscale(0%)"
                        emoji = null;
                        emojiCount++;
                    }
                }else if(emojiCount>3){
                    if(emoji.style.height == 200+"px")
                    {
                        emoji.style.width = 150+"px";
                        emoji.style.height = 150+"px";
                        emoji.style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
                        emoji = null;
                        emojiCount--;
                    }else{
                        emoji = null;
                    }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Add as a snippet. So it can be understood easily.

Comment: Basically I used this video to create the draggable objects, and then put them in a div container https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CacIQoN2Ty4&t=118s&ab_channel=joylearn